Querying nested JSON files in Powershell
I have nested JSON file (saved on HDD as file.json):
    Val: [
    {str1: "REQ", 
     num1: 001, 
     Arr1: [
     {"id": "e6ddf4538b20",
     "displayName": "CA015",                    
     "result": "fail"},
    {"id": "538b20e6ddf4",
    "displayName": "CA014",                    
    "result": "na"}]
    },
    {str1: "AVL", 
     num1: 002, 
     Arr1: [
     {"id": "0e63d114",
     "displayName": "CA015",                    
     "result": "fail"},
     {"id": "0e63d1140e6ddf4",
     "displayName": "CA014",                    
     "result": "success"}]},
{str1: "unst", 
         num1: 003, 
         Arr1: [
         {"id": "o44k63jz14",
         "displayName": "CA015",                    
         "result": "success"},
         {"id": "0e63d1140e6ddf4",
         "displayName": "CA014",                    
         "result": "success"}]}
        ]

I can successfully import the JSON.
$imp = get-content -path 'c:\temp\file.json | out-string | convertFrom-json

Now, I want to query (for each object in Val array) if $imp.Arr1.displayName -like '*015' -and $imp.Arr1.result -eq 'fail' and return Str1, num1

Aside you not needing to pipe through Out-String: what is the question?
You pretty much have the code already.
(also your JSON like that isn't correctly formatted and shouldn't be parsed by ConvertFrom-Json, throwing a error. Copied it wrong?)

The JSON here is a sample, could be wrong. Overall, the JSON structure is, Val = has an array of objects, each object has members, each member is a single value and one member is an array of objects. I want to query the nested array objects to find the parent object values from.

Please update the question specifying the JSON snippet is just a partial example of the JSON file. Also: you have quite literally the anser in your own question. Check the official docs if you have any doubt https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach

As commented by @sirtao, from a StackOverflow question standpoint, I would recommend you to follow the how to ask guidelines and create an Minimal, Reproducible Example next time.
In fact, if you would have done so, you might have already found out from similar questions that ConvertFrom-Json returns PSCustomObjects by default.
It is unclear from you question with PowerShell version you using knowing that in the later PowerShell versions the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet has a -AsHashTable parameter which allows you to use the dot-notation as suggested in your question.
Anyways, as a common answer to this general question, you might use this ObjectGraphTools module which is able to treat any (hashtable) dictionary or PSCustomObject equally. Besides, it has an extended dot notation (Xdn) which helps you to easily target any node independent of it's depth:
Install-Module -Name ObjectGraphTools

Using the Get-Node cmdlet:
$Data = Get-content -path c:\temp\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Node = $Data | Get-Node ~displayName=*15..result=fail....
$Node

Path   Name Depth Value
----   ---- ----- -----
Val[0]    0     2 @{str1=REQ; num1=1; Arr1=System.Object[]}
Val[1]    1     2 @{str1=AVL; num1=2; Arr1=System.Object[]}

Explanation:

~displayName=*15 queries any descendant leaf node named displayName and a value like *15
.. gets the parent node
result=fail selects the direct child nodes named result and a value of fail
.... gets the great-grandparent node

To get the concerned Str1 and num1 leaf child nodes, you might use the Get-ChildNode cmdlet:
$Node | Get-ChildNode -Leaf

Path        Name Depth Value
----        ---- ----- -----
Val[0].str1 str1     3 REQ
Val[0].num1 num1     3 1
Val[1].str1 str1     3 AVL
Val[1].num1 num1     3 2

or:
($Node | Get-Node str1).Value
REQ
AVL

or:
($Data | Get-Node ~displayName=*15..result=fail....str1=REQ..num1).Value
1

To change the specific value:
($Data | Get-Node ~displayName=*15..result=fail....str1=REQ..num1).Value = 3
$Data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 # ...


thank you iRon and Sirtao for your help. I agree, I should've been more specific and constructed my question as the guideline.
